# Regular expression for time 08:00 - 21:00 in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc

I need a regular expression for an input field that matches any hour between 08:00 and 21:00 including. This means that hours like 08:00, 12:47, 16:19 and 21:00 are correct. 07:59, 21:01, 22:00, etc. are incorrect.

I came up with this reg ex `(([01]?[8-9]|20):[0-5][0-9])|21:00` and I thought it was working, but then I figured out that in fact it is not. All hours between 10:00 and 19:59 are incorrect. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this?

`(0[8-9]:[0-5][0-9]|1[0-9]:[0-5][0-9]|20:[0-5][0-9]|21:00)`

It is shown in this example [here](https://regex101.com/r/pZ1yW2/1) to be working as you wish it to.